# Django: Programmatically determine path to an admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

If I have the admin module enabled for a certain model, is there a way to determine what the full URL will be for the page to create a new instance of that model?

What I'm looking for is something like this following:

```
"Please <a href='%s'>create</a> some Foo models" % Foo.AdminCreateUrl
```

**Update**: To clarify, this needs to be done on the backend rather than on the templating layer.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
DisabledMessage = "No foos exist. Please <a href='%s'>create</a> some before assigning bars." \
                    % urlresolvers.reverse('admin:app_foo_add')
```

This does not work. I get the following error message:

> ImproperlyConfigured at
>   /admin/bar/bar/add/
>
> The included urlconf mysite.urls doesn't
>   have any patterns in it

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, read this.  The admin site must be properly activated.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overview

Second, read this.  This is how the admin URI names work.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls

I think you can use the `{% url %}` template tag.

```
Please <a href="{% url "admin:app_Foo_add" %}">create</a> some Foo models
```

Comment: This admin site is properly activated and works fine. I noticed that when I remove the `reverse()` call, the same ImproperlyConfigured error is triggered on the `import urlresolvers` statement.

Comment: "ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/bar/bar/add/" and "properly activated" seem contradictory.

Comment: Well, the admin interface works fine until I add that import statement. What do you mean by "activated"?

Comment: The referenced doc says "There are six steps in activating the Django admin site:".  That's what I mean by "activated".

Answer (score 1):

[Reversing admin urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls).